# Alternative to _mm_shuffle_ps that can take 3 elements from one source?

Tags: x86, sse, simd

[_mm_shuffle_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_shuffle_ps&expand=4743) can just copy 2 floats from `a` and 2 from `b`, right? Is there any easy way to get 3 floats from `a` and 1 from `b`? I also noticed that `_mm_move_ss` can do part of the job, but it doesn't do shift.

Ref:

```c
__m128 _mm_shuffle_ps(__m128 a, __m128 b, unsigned int imm8)
```

Comment: It depends on whether you can assume a minimum SSE version, e.g. SSSE3 or SSE4 ?

Comment: I can use SSE3 and SSE4.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SSE4 then use [BLENDPS](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_blend_ps&expand=4743,405), for which the intrinsic is:

```c
__m128 _mm_blend_ps (__m128 v1, __m128 v2, const int mask);
```

Comment: The beauty of _mm_shuffle_ps is it can do some kind of shift work, but _mm_blend_ps cannot.

Comment: @echo: if that's what you need then you should probably edit your question to include that requirement

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only 2-source shuffles are `movss`, `movsd`, `shufps`, `unpckl/hps/d`, `movhlps`, and similar non-flexible instructions.

[`palignr` might be useful](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PALIGNR.html), even with the bypass delay for using an int shuffle between FP instructions, if your data-movement needs fit its pattern.

AVX512 adds 2-source full shuffles (lane-crossing, with a vector selector), for various element sizes.  Stuff like [`vpermi2w`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1048,1048,1356,2263,2936,1798,2377,2263,3905,3867,1643,411,3124,3130,3130,3964,3919&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512&text=vpermi2) and `vpermt2b`

As Paul points out, blends are the flexible way to combine data from 2 regs without shuffling.

---

See [Agner Fog's Optimizing Assembly guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) for a table of instructions organized by type of data movement.  See also the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki.